# Renaming folder in JStree

Tags: c#, jquery, jstree

I am trying to rename a folder in my jstree, which should update the new name in database.
While trying to do that i got the following error :

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'css' in jquery.jstree.js file
```

MyCode :

```
.bind("rename.jstree", function (e, data) {
        $.post(
            "./ajax/server.aspx",
            {
                "operation": "rename_node",
                "id": data.rslt.obj.attr("id"),
                "title": data.rslt.new_name
            },
            function (r) {
                if (!r.status) {
                    $.jstree.rollback(data.rlbk);
                }
            }
        );
    })

Function to update New Name in DB

 private void rename_node()
    {
        int _id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        string _folder_name = Request.QueryString["title"];
        try
        {
            _subscription_api.rename(_id, _folder_name);
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("-1");
        }
    }
```

I am new to JS tree and JQuery. I am trying to call a function from my js file, so that the function updates the new folder name to database. But on right click of my folder and clicking Rename, i get the above error.

Comment: use a console in a different browser than IE to get more detailed error report. Post a link to page

Comment: You probably already checked this but I have made this mistake in the past so its worth a mention... Is the jquery script tag included before the jstree script tag?